# How to restrict access to root to daemon user?

Tags: security, php5, httpd.conf, apache-2.4, directory

I have Apache 2.4 with PHP 5.5.14 installed on latest Debian. According to Apache security tips&tricks I've set my httpd.conf to this:

```
<Directory />
  AllowOverride none
  Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www">
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride none
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I restart the Apache server and run this PHP code:

```
<?php
  $filename = "/etc/passwd";
  $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
  $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
  fclose($handle);
  echo($contents);
?>
```

The code gets the whole /etc/passwd file and I consider it a huge security issue. Now, I've been trying to solve this for a couple of days now simply by reading the manuals, but I had no luck yet. I'd appreacte a push in the right directions, thanx.

Comment: how about open_basedir parameter? http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

Comment: Now, I feel stupid because that's exactly the solution I was looking for. Missed it in the php.ini... Post it as answer and I'll mark it. Thanx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But be aware that `open_basedir` will just restrict directory access for PHP functions and the like but not for external programs that are being executed via PHP. For example:

```
    <?php
    $file = shell_exec('cat /etc/passwd');
    echo $file;
```

will output the contents of the `/etc/passwd` file without a problem, because the filesystem access is not invoked by PHP itself but the `cat` program. `cat` is run by the `www-data` user by default (on Debian), so just regular OS file access permissions will apply here (i.e access for file owner, group and world).

To prevent that, you can either

- disable functions like `exec()`, `passthru()`, `system()`, `shell_exec()` that execute shell commands via [`disable_functions`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) in your `php.ini`,
- change the permission of the files, so the user running the webserver (or PHP) doesn't have permission to read the file or
- put Apache or PHP in a chroot jail (though I've never tried that myself).

Depending on your Apache/PHP configuration and your needs, the `disable_functions` is probably the easiest to set up, but it will likely break things like ImageMagick and stuff, that is often with `exec()` (like `exec('/usr/bin/convert ...')` for ImageMagick).

I tested that on Debian Squeeze with Apache and PHP as mod_php from the repositories and Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache and PHP run via php-fpm, also with the packages from the repository. Probably that will also apply to PHP on Windows, but I never tried that... though `cat /etc/passwd` *won't* work :-)

Comment: Thanx a lot for the tip! I realize that, I already disabled some functions that might compromise my system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameter `open_basedir` defined in *php.ini*. This parameter will prevent the  PHP script accessing file (such as **fopen()** or **include()**) outside the directory specified in open_basedir. See [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) for documentation.